# Sorting this multidimention array in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have tried this problem 
how do you sort this  array using the value that is elements in [1].
I would also appreciate if someone demonstrate how print each key and it's value of this
array

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 0
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 290
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 852
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 9
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 896
    )
)
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use **uasort**

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

To print each key, value... just iterate over it with a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)